# Obtener texto de un atributo con jQuery

Tags: jquery

tengo el siguiente problema.
De que manera puedo obtener del valor año **(2021)** del atributo **content** del elemento **span** y ponerlo como texto en el ultimo **span**

```
<span class="start-date" itemprop="startDate" content="2021-06-30T20:00:00+0000">
    <span class="we-date-format-custom wvc-bigtext bigtext" id="bigtext-id0">
       <span class="we-month bigtext-line0">Jun</span>
       <span class="we-day bigtext-line1">30</span>
       <span class="we-year bigtext-line2" style="">2021</span>
    </span>         
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, le puse un ID al primer `<span>`, y un ID al `<span>` donde vamos a poner el texto del `content`.
Después utilizamos `Jquery` para asignar el valor que sacamos de `content`. **¿Cómo lo hace?** fácil:

- `$(document).ready`: es la función que corre cuando se carga la página al completo
- `$(".we-year").text()`: Obtenermos el `<span>` donde pondremos el dato, y el método `text()` permite asignarle un valor.
- `$(".start-date").attr("content")`: Obtenemos el atributo `content` del `<span>` StartDate.
- `.split("-")[0]`: permite separar el texto obtenido del punto anterior en un arreglo de `strings`, usamos como criterio de separación los guiones medios. como el año está en la primera pocisión del arreglo, obtenemos la posición `[0]`.

El código queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<span class="start-date" itemprop="startDate" id="StartDate" content="2021-06-30T20:00:00+0000">
        <span class="we-date-format-custom wvc-bigtext bigtext" id="bigtext-id0">
           <span class="we-month bigtext-line0">Jun</span>
           <span class="we-day bigtext-line1">30</span>
           <span class="we-year bigtext-line2" id="yearDate"></span>
        </span>         
    </span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".we-year").text($(".start-date").attr("content").split("-")[0]);
        });
    </script>
```

**EDIT**
considera que al obtener datos por clase con `Jquery`, puede que la clase se utilice en algún otro elemento, y podría hacer que esto no funcione.

Comment: Hola, no puedo añadir ningun id ni modificar el codigo, pero me fue muy util su respuesta, basada en ella encontre la solucion, mil gracias.

Comment: cambié las ID's por las clases html que ya tienes

Answer (score 0):

Buen Día.
Creo que lo que puedes hacer es esto:

Lo que hago es asignar un id "date" a el span de la fecha y un id "editable" a el span a cambiar, tomo el atributo content con la primera linea y creo una instancia de Date con los datos del atributo content finalmente remplazo el texto del ultimo span con la función innnerText por el año que se toma con la instancia de Date y la función getFullYear XD.

```
<script>
resource=document.getElementById("date").getAttribute("content");
const date=new Date(resource);
document.getElementById("editable").innerText=date.getFullYear();
</script>
```

Comment: puedes explicar qué hace esto? además, no se recomienda usar imágenes como respuesta (por ejemplo, en mi trabajo no me dejan verlas por proxy). sí eso es código, puedes ponerlo en vez de la imagen?

Comment: lo siento es que no queria escribir:

Comment: listo ya lo edite por si te interesa

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo pude solucionar exactamente de esta manera, me base en la respuesta de arriba y solamente en vez de usar IDs lo que hago es que llago a la clase CSS para identificar el componente.

```
 <script> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $( ".we-date-format-custom" ).append( "<span class='we-year bigtext-line2' style=''></span>" );
    $(".we-year").text($(".start-date").attr("content").split("-")[0]);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: al hacerlo así, necesitas eliminar del html lo que estás poniendo dentro del `append` para que funcione. vale la pena aclararlo.